# How to ScrollLeft 50% and ScrollTop using jQuery

Tags: jquery, height, width

I have the solution. I noticed new trainees find it difficult to implement some functionality at times.

**Strongly not for ratings but for education purposes**

Comment: Creating a question to answer yourself is absolutely fine, and encouraged, however the question itself needs to state a clear problem description and expected result. Yours does neither. The question should already not have been answered somewhere else. As you can see from the duplicates, this is also not the case here.

Comment: I agree @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

```
let scroll_width = $('.the-class').width();
let scroll_height = $('.some-class').height() / 2; //for half of..
$('.some-class').scrollLeft(scroll_width);
$('.some-class').scrollTop(scroll_height);
```